# Как заполнять автоматически дату изменения ячеек в двух столбцах

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так и как исправить? Вообще не силен в программировании, по образцу пытался сделать не получилось (

Нужно, чтобы при изменении ячейки в столбце B (обращение), подставлялась дата и время этого изменения в столбец Е (время обращение). (Эта часть работает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]И чтобы при изменении ячейки в столбце D (Ответ), подставлялось дата и время этого ответа в столбец F (время ответа).
Вот со второй частью проблемы, не подставляет дату в столбец F.
Ниже сам скрипт который использую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что исправить нужно?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet10 = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var idCol10 = e.range.getColumn();
  var idRow = e.range.getRow();
  var idRow10 = e.range.getRow();
  if (idCol == 2 && sheet.getName() == 'Лист1') {
    // Какой столбец смотрим изменения для первой даты
    var Value = e.range.offset(0, +3).getValues(); // Смотрим что в ячейке справа дата еще не заполнена ((0, +1) ячейка саправа (0, -1) ячейка слева (0, -2) ячейка слева через одну
    if (Value == '') {
      var vartoday = getDate();
      sheet.getRange(idRow, 5).setValue(vartoday); //В какой столбец вставляем дату
    }
  }

  if (idCol == 4 && sheet10.getName() == 'Лист1') {
    // Какой столбец смотрим изменения для второй даты
    var Value10 = e.range.offset(0, +2).getValues(); // Смотрим что в ячейке справа дата еще не заполнена ((0, +1) ячейка саправа (0, -1) ячейка слева (0, -2) ячейка слева через одну
    if (Value == '') {
      var vartoday10 = getDate();
      sheet10.getRange(idRow10, 6).setValue(vartoday10); //В какой столбец вставляем вторую дату
    }
  }
}
// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
  var today = new Date(); //объявлем первую дату
  today.setDate(today.getDate()); //получаем первую дату
  var today10 = new Date(); //объявлем вторую дату
  today10.setDate(today.getDate()); //получаем вторую дату
  //return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
  return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+04:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy : HH:mm'); //Формат даты для первой даты
  return Utilities.formatDate(today10, 'GMT+04:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy : HH:mm'); //Формат даты для второй даты
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если для одной функции, то

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var idRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (idCol === 2 && sheet.getName() === 'Лист1') {
    if (e.range.offset(0, 3).getValue() === '') {
      sheet.getRange(idRow, 5).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

  if (idCol === 4 && sheet.getName() === 'Лист1') {
    if (e.range.offset(0, 2).getValue() === '') {
      sheet.getRange(idRow, 6).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```